# Генерация ключа, для пользователя

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Каким образом монжно сделать генерацию(цифрового) ключа около 6 цифр, надо чтобы каждый пользователь имел свой ключ, и чтоб он не повторялся. Розглядал uuid но там генериться сложный ключ, и я не нашел как изменить генерацию. но можно же методом random, если ним, то должна быть какая-та валидация, и как я понял кастомная. Так вот, кастомные валидации я не писал, хотелось бы помощи или хотябы перенаправьте на правильные источники

Comment: Именно 6 цифр? Не мало? Это 1 000 000 аккаунтов (а один человек их может завести несколько), потом ключи неизбежно будут повторяться. Или вам ключ нужен на короткий срок?

Comment: Есть такое понятие "XY-проблема", когда вопрос не о проблеме, а о неудачной попытке её решения. Расскажите, зачем вам это надо, скорее всего, есть более адекватное решение.

Comment: @Андрей-Шостик для этого обычно slug используется, попробуйте `friendly_id` gem

Comment: @cheops > *Это 1 000 000 аккаунтов*.
Не вполне, если он имеет ввиду slug, то это обычно не 10^6, а 26^6 или даже 36^6 (~2-х млрд)=)